# How to get all text files from a folder in ascending sequence?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am using this code:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Powercel\TimeStats\TimeStats_50slots" -Filter *.txt |Foreach-Object{
    write-host $_.BaseName             
    $cnt= $_.BaseName.Length
    if($cnt -eq 23){
        $f= $_.BaseName.Substring(0,$_.BaseName.Length-1) 
    }ElseIf($cnt -eq 24){
        $f= $_.BaseName.Substring(0,$_.BaseName.Length-2)
    }ElseIf($cnt -eq 25){
        $f= $_.BaseName.Substring(0,$_.BaseName.Length-3)
    }

    if($f -match "21_01_2016_13TimeStats"){
        $data = Get-Content $_.FullName -Encoding Unicode 
        foreach ($line in $data){
            write-host $line
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to fetch all text files from a folder but they are coming in a different order. Something like this :

1 file than 10 file than 11 ->12 ->13 and than 2 file and than 3 -> 4 like this.

But I need it in sequence like this 1-> 2-> 3->4->5........13

File names look like:

```
21_01_2016_13TimeStats1.txt
21_01_2016_13TimeStats2.txt
21_01_2016_13TimeStats3.txt
21_01_2016_13TimeStats4.txt
# etc...
```

So could anyone please help me out ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Sort-Object`.

By default, `Sort-Object` performs an alphabetical sort, so you'll have to use a sort expression that converts the last part of the files' basenames to an int during sorting.

Given your filenames look like `[date]TimeStats[number].txt`, you could do something like:

```
('21_01_2016_13TimeStats2' -split '\D'|Select -Last 1) -as [int]
```

To grab the digit(s) at the end and convert to `[int]`:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt |Sort-Object { ($_.BaseName -split '\D'|Select -Last 1) -as [int] } |ForEach-Object { <# do your thing #> }
```

---

PowerShell 2.0 doesn't have the unchecked type conversion operator `-as`, so you'll have to do:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt |Sort-Object { try{[int]($_.BaseName -split '\D'|Select -Last 1)}catch{} } |ForEach-Object { <# do your thing #> }
```

Comment: Still it is accessing the file in some random order

Comment: @LovepreetSingh 1,10,11,12 is not random, it's alphabetical. What is the actual file names? If they contain both letters and numbers the above approach won't work without some modification

Comment: this is the sequence of file in a folder i want in this sequence only...                             
21_01_2016_13TimeStats1.txt
21_01_2016_13TimeStats2.txt
21_01_2016_13TimeStats3.txt
21_01_2016_13TimeStats4.txt
21_01_2016_13TimeStats5.txt
21_01_2016_13TimeStats6.txt
21_01_2016_13TimeStats7.txt
21_01_2016_13TimeStats8.txt
21_01_2016_13TimeStats9.txt
21_01_2016_13TimeStats10.txt
21_01_2016_13TimeStats11.txt
21_01_2016_13TimeStats12.txt
21_01_2016_13TimeStats13.txt